# Port 53 open when scanned

Tags: samsung

Why is my phone showing a DNS port as open? Wouldn't that mean someone has spyware on my phone and that they are connecting through port 53?

Comment: Are you talking about TCP port 53 or UDP port 53?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you make you phone a Wi-Fi hotspot, it runs a DNS server so that clients can forward their DNS queries to it.

Comment: Are you talking about TCP port 53 or UDP port 53? – 
Robert
 I think its UDP